# php download a file with curl that returns binary data

Tags: php, curl, binary

Im trying to hit a url that returns binary data and use to save the file. When i try using file_put_contents the file gets generated but the contents are empty or file says its damaged.

```
 $url_call = 'http://someurl.com/file/15646';

 $ch=curl_init();   
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_call);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); 
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);


 file_put_contents('/data/testingdirect.pdf', $response);
```

I know theres many questions out there similar and iv looked through all of them and tried them but they all return the same result a damaged or empty file.

I know the file is good because I can actually access that file myself directly on the server and see that its good.

Also is there a way for me to determine the file type or content type to know how to save the fil either pdf or jpeg or whatever else.?

REWROTE THE CURL TO BE THIS:

```
 $fp = fopen ('/data/testingdirect.jpg', 'w+');
 $ch=curl_init();   
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_call);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

and same thing is still happening.

Comment: What happens when you try viewing `testingdirect.pdf` as plaintext? (The downloaded file -> Edit with Notepad) Also have you tried `false` for `BINARYTRANSFER`?

Comment: I see the binary data

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 20:36:05 GMT
Etag: af362918b9ee35b969cdsfdfe4db2b0e7
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3906609
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 22:55:17 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Open a file handle, then pass it to CURLOPT_FILE.

```
$tempFP = fopen('/data/testingdirect.pdf', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE , $tempFP);
```

When you do your curl exec, the results will go into that file pointer

Dont forget to close the file handle

Answer (score -2):

If your url is secured then you might need to set SSL_VERIFYPEER to false;

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$url = 'example.com/';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$con = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```